# How can I find the instance calling another Magento object's method from within that object?

Tags: php, oop, magento

A client has asked me to reduce the complexity of Magento's `…/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml` so that it only asks for (US) *Zip Code*, bypassing *Country* and *Region*, and then furthermore assumes the first shipping option. (Order to be determined by client in the admin). In order to do that, I need to override the `estimatePostAction` method from `…/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` so that it assumes the result from `estimateUpdatePostAction` (from the same class).

I'm stuck trying to choose the first shipping option.

The problem I'm having is that the *valid* shipping values are calculated in the shipping.phtml template via a loop over `$this->getEstimateRates()`. How can I get the object that is represented by `$this` from within my overriding `CartController` class in order to calculate the shipping options?

Note: This is Magento EE ver. 1.11.2.0

If you find the above tl;dr, here's a summary what I'm trying to do:

- Override checkout/cart/shipping template so that it:

  - Only asks for *Zip Code*
  - Automatically chooses the first available valid shipping option without asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` you can access shipping values which you have in `/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml` (`$this->getEstimateRates()`) in next way:

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();`

Answer (score 1):

`$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates()` shall return you the collection of shipping rates. Haven't tried it by myself though.

Comment: …but I'm in the `CartController` class. It doesn't have a `getQuote` method.

Comment: You can use $this->getCheckout()->getQuote() from any template file or Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote() from anywhere else.